# Create a webpage that streams a python value that changes every second?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, apache

I have a python script that is reading some sensor data on my raspberry pi. I have the code setup and the python script pauses and returns the newest value after one second. I want to display the newest value on a web page without having to refresh it. What is the best way to do this? I am running an Apache server, but I am not opposed to switching to something like flup, if need be. I am thinking I could use jquery and ajax, but I don't want to go down the rabbit hole, if there is an easier way.

Thanks for answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, but I guess the easiest way would be to write the value to file that is accessible to apache, then put an ajax request in a setInterval loop, something like:

```
setInterval(function () {
  $.get('/sensor/value', function (resp) {
    console.log(resp);
    $('#data_container').html(resp);
  })
}, 1000)
```

There are far deeper rabbit holes, like websockets, for which this is perfect use case. They are however much more work.

Comment: Websockets is the rightest way to do this in terms of resources - the naive non-websocket implementation you offer certainly would work but would have a significant amount of overhead compared to something smart enough to just block on a socket. The other option would be having a service that knows how to 'chunk' HTTP responses. Chunking is part of the standard HTTP protocol but not generally in the toolbox of most web service developers - it has the advantage of being universally supported where websockets may not be.